# Is my 100% ticket actually refundable?

Tags: international-travel, refunds, return

So I've booked a round-trip ticket with Latam, from the US to Argentina. Thing is, I purposefully booked the return ticket ( Argentina-US) %100 refundable whereas the flight US-Argentina is 30% refundable. The reason for that is my grandfather is sick and he's already been sent home as there's not much the doctors can do to help. I just want to spend time with him and my family in this difficult time, maybe a month or two, depending on how things go even longer. But I didn't want to have a set date, I wanted more flexibility and that's why I bought the return ticket 100% refundable. However I came across this on my ticket this morning: "No refund permitted after the first flight on your itinerary departs". Are they referring to my flight into Argentina? Or the first flight on the return itinerary (Argentina-US)? I'm very confused now, what's the point of it being refundable if I don't have the flexibility I need at the moment?

Edits:
To make it clear
Los Angeles - Buenos Aires March 23 30% refund
Burnos aires - Los Angeles April 22 100% refund

Comment: Your question isn’t clear. What is your full itinerary? Which ticket are you referring to? And which part of ‘the first flight on your itinerary’ is difficult to understand?

Comment: Not sure, so not an answer, but it probably means that if you cancel before leaving the US, you can get 30% refund on the US-Argentina flight and 100% refund on the return Argentina-US flight. But once you take the first US-Argentina leg, you can no longer get any refund even if you don't take the Argentina-US flight.

Comment: Is it one round trip itinerary or two separate itineraries, with different booking numbers?

Comment: I booked this as one round trip itinerary, same reservation code. What I find weird is that they let me select how refundable I wanted each way to be, giving a sense that they were two independent itineraries.

Comment: That's the way it looks to me. I would refund the return segment _now_, and rebook it as a separate ticket.

Comment: If you keep digging you'll probably also find a condition that states that the most restrictive conditions apply to the entire ticket, and that would be the 30% refund conditions...

Comment: That is so confusing... Why would they make me pay more for a ticket and then apply the more restrictive conditions? I don't get it lol each fare should have its own restrictions. Anyhow, I'm not sure they will let me cancel just the return segment now, I will get in youch with the airline

Comment: It **may** be possible that here “itinerary” means a sequence of connecting flights, so if you had a stop on the way, you couldn’t get a refund after departure of the first flight in that sequence. But you would have to dig deep in the fare rules or ask them to be sure.

Comment: @chrizz Why would they do that?  To make a profit, of course.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

So, I remembered I took pictures of the screen when I was purchasing it. And this is what it said! That I'm able to either change or refund my ticket before of after flight time.